# I want to understand spring framework source

Tags: java, spring

I want to understand spring framework source is there any helpful links for that, Basically I want to learn how spring is capable of doing dependency injection, how spring mvc servlet works, how view resolvers works etc..

Comment: The /src directory that comes with every Spring download has all the source code.  You can look at it all you like, but it's unlikely that you'll get the "how" from reviewing a few files.

Comment: If you go to your favorite search engine and copy paste each part of that (e.g. "how spring is capable of doing dependency injection") you will probably discover a few 'helpful links'.  Why not try that and come back to us when you have a *specific* question?  Voting to close.

Comment: I am not asking where can I download spring framework, is there any resources to understand or explaining spring source

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to understand is going through their code http://www.springsource.org/download

Comment: The code can be confusing, and it is hard to debug to understand also.  It involves a lot of proxies, so try looking for a guide on the basic concepts, THEN dig into the code.

Answer (score 0):

Spring have **excellent** [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) and [javaDoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/). All information is there, just need to look carefully. If you want to look at the concrete realisation, look at the spring framework source directly.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many, I would try to start with the official site: http://www.springsource.org/
and do some tutorials.

any way spring is very very large that contains all kind of things- DI, AOP, MVC, SpringIntegration and so on...
You will probably want to play a bit with each one (and download STS)...